# Multiple selections from a list in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to figure out why my code is not wokring for my excel on Macbook.

```
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Address = "$D$7" Or Target.Address = "$D$8" Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
    If Oldvalue = "" Then
      Target.Value = Newvalue
    Else
      If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
        Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

When I try to test in in the sheet, it does not affect anything and therefore nothing changes.

I still can only choice one value to be presented in teh given cell, from a list of 100 values.

Anyone can help me fiqure out teh solution?

Tried many things, nothing seem to work

Comment: Presumably this is the `Worksheet_Change` event handler. Is this in a sheet code module, not a regular module? Can you use `Debug.Print` statements to trace execution flow?

Comment: Try commenting out this line `On Error GoTo Exitsub` and see what happens, you may have an error, but with this line application just silently goes out. And also, it would have been great to understand the purpose of this code

Comment: Try run `Application.EnableEvents = True` in VBE Immediate Window